# Xcode: Setting GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS for different build configurations?

Tags: iphone, xcode, build, preprocessor

I want to set `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` for each of my four build configurations (Debug, Release, Ad Hoc, and Distribution.) I'd like to have a different setting for each.

The screen I'm looking at is the Target Info window's "Build" tab. When I set the Configuration pop-up to "Debug" I can see my `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` setting there. When I switch to "Release," or any of the other configurations, it's no longer visible. Yet when I try to add it to those configurations, it says `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` already exists, and that I can't add it again.

As I said, I want to have a different setting for my various builds. How can I accomplish this?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure there isn't a setting called "Preprocessor Macros".  This is the same as `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS`.

Comment: That's it! Thanks very much.

My only confusion now is: why is "Preprocessor Macros" not listed under my DEBUG configuration, but listed under every other configuration? How can I change that?

Thanks again!

Comment: That question I for not have an answer for.  Sorry, but I'm glad I could help you on the other thing.

Comment: The answer to that is in the other thread. By the way, posting a picture of what you are seeing would really help diagnose it faster.

Answer (score 3):

OTHER_CFLAGS if I understood the question right. And pass your defines like `-DDEBUG` or something.

And yes, if you need to assign a value to a macro, you could do something like this - `'-DSOME_MESSAGE=@"Hello, World!"'`.
Note ' symbols around - they are required. SOME_MESSAGE macro will be defined with @"Hello, World!" value.