# Cordova iOS build enable DEBUG for #ifdef DEBUG in CDVDebug.h

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm developing a plugin for iOS Cordova. I've created an iOS Cordova application project using the Cordova CLI tools. I would like to enable the debug macros defined in CDVDebug.h with the -DDEBUG compiler flag. Is there a way I can do this from within Xcode when I have the Cordova project open in Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question this [Xcode: Setting GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS for different build configurations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540322/xcode-setting-gcc-preprocessor-definitions-for-different-build-configurations) talks about preprocessor options. Additionally:

1. Debug logging with NSLog in CDVCommandQueue and CDVLocalStorage is set controlled by OTHER_FLAGS = -DDEBUG in the CordovaLib.xcodeproj file. The setting can be found by typing into the search box in “Build Settings” pane.
2. Debug logging with NSLog in CDVUserAgentUtil and CDVWebViewDelegate is controlled by uncommenting // #define VerboseLog NSLog and commenting #define VerboseLog(...) do {} while (0)
3. By default the cordova build command has the --debug option in play which sets the flag -DDEBUG.